Windows page table memory leak - how to debug?
After running for just a single day, the 32GB system RAM on my Windows machine would become full, but without any process using significant memory. Task manager shows that processes under my user took only 4.4GB, and I'm the only user on the system.
System info: Lenovo IdeaPad Pro 14 2024
CPU: AMD 7840HS
GPU: Radeon 780m
Ram: 32GB DDR5 soldered (allocated 4GB Vram in BIOS)
OS: Windows 11

Sysinternals RamMap definitely shows that something is wrong, there's 8GB of total ram in "Unused" pool but almost all of them are active (used), and the page tables for 32GB of ram shouldn't take 7GB either. One very strange behaviour I noticed is that in the RamMap Processes tab, 90% of my processes are docker.exe, comhost, and com.docker.cli, even though I'm not running docker desktop. Is this normal?



"even though I'm not running docker desktop." - If you are not running Docker Desktop, why do you have it installed? Do you have WSL2 installed? You should [edit] your question and clarify it; while neither Docker nor WSL2 likely has anything to do with your issue, understanding your system configuration is very helpful.

@Ramhound what I mean is, I didn't start docker desktop and it's not running in the background and still there's a huge number of docker cli zombie processes - they're probably invoked by something else.

@Ramhound and yes wsl2 is installed.

@Ramhound I added some system info. Let me know what you think or what else would be relevant.

What do you have running within WSL and Docker? Docker is using a lot of memory if your not actually wanting to run anything in it.
